# Message in autocomplete (primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I would like to enter a message (eg. "Please select one") in the element p:autocomplete.
It's possible? Of course, the string can not be a valid value.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a good look at the PrimeFaces showcase and documentation (all suggested answers are in there)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<p:autoComplete id="autocomp"
value="#{Bean.name}"
completeMethod="#{Bean.completeMethod}" var="app"
itemValue="#{app}" itemLabel="#{app}" forceSelection="true"
selectListener="#{Bean.listener}"
minQueryLength="4" onSelectUpdate="dialogpanel" />


<p:watermark for="autocomp"
value="wartermark text" onclick="PrimeFaces.cleanWatermarks();" oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();"/>
<h:outputText value="Type four or more characters for search suggestions" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<p:autoComplete placeholder="Please select one"/>
```